# write() return errno 14 why?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have `unsigned int DataBAR` and want to send `char` to the serial port!

My code is:

```
unsigned char Printer_buffer[PRN_BUFFER_SIZE];  
unsigned int DataBAR, DataD, DataT;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  SumaN = SumaN + (Printer_buffer[i] & 0x0F);
  DataBAR = (Printer_buffer[i] & 0x0F) + 0x30;
  nbytes = write(fd,DataBAR ,1); //want to send to the serial port 
  printf("write error  code is %d !!!!!!!!!\n", errno);
  if (nbytes != 1) {
    printf("error writing on serial port!!!\n");
  }
  sleep(1);
  SumaP = SumaP + ((Printer_buffer[i] >> 4) & 0x0F);
  DataBAR = ((Printer_buffer[i] >> 4) & 0x0F) + 0x30;
  nbytes = write(fd, DataBAR, 1);
  printf("write error  code is %d !!!!!!!!!\n", errno);
  if (nbytes != 1) {
    printf("error writing on serial port!!!\n");
  }
  sleep(1);
}
```

`write` returns `errno=14` how to solve this problem?

With pic18f in C I use this code and it is working:

```
for (i=0;i<8;i++){
  SumaN=SumaN+(Printer_buffer[i] & 0x0F);
  DataBAR=(Printer_buffer[i] & 0x0F) + 0x30;
  while(BusyUART1());
  putcUART1(DataBAR);               
  SumaP=SumaP+((Printer_buffer[i]>>4) & 0x0F);
  DataBAR=((Printer_buffer[i]>>4) & 0x0F) + 0x30;
  while(BusyUART1());
  putcUART1(DataBAR);               
}
```

I`m now in this and thanks for your help!!!

Comment: errno 14 = bad address, how do you open the `fd` ?

Comment: fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
 if (fd == -1) {
  perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0\n");
  exit(1);
 }

Comment: serial  port configuration :     tcgetattr(fd, &termAttr);
 //baudRate = B115200;          /* Not needed */
 cfsetispeed(&termAttr, B57600);
 cfsetospeed(&termAttr, B57600);
 termAttr.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
 termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
 termAttr.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
 termAttr.c_cflag |= CS8;
 termAttr.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
 termAttr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
 termAttr.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
 termAttr.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
 termAttr.c_cc[VMIN] = 3;
 termAttr.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;
 tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &termAttr);

Comment: please add that to your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`write()` is `int write( int fd, void *buf, int n )` so you must not pass an integer as second parameter. I guess you haven't included `unistd.h` otherwise your code shouldn'et even compile. Instead refer to [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) and call

```
write( fd, &DataBAR, 1 )
```

But be aware that it depends on the endiannes of your system whether you write the most or the least significant byte by doing that. Better define `DataBAR` as char (or copy the value into a char `c` and use `&c` in `write()`)

Comment: Well, OP wants to send a `char`, so `n` would just be 1 (though you could argue that endianness could then play an issue).